# View bottom border for CPTBarPlots

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is there any way to move up bar plots created using CorePlot so that the bottom borders are visible??

here's my code for setting up plots.I tried assigning value to baseValue to see if it helped

```
for (CPTBarPlot *plot in plots) {
        plot.dataSource = self;
        plot.delegate = self;
        plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(CPDBarWidth);
        plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(barX);
        plot.barBasesVary =NO;
        plot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
        plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
        [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
        barX += CPDBarWidth;

    }
```

if i don't set the baseValue , the bottom portion of the bars are cut off.When i set baseValue as in the  code the, the bars are raised but then zero valued bars get some height too and the graph looks weird.I just want to see bars with borders on four sides.

Comment: Can you add some pictures tha show what you want and what you have currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bar border is getting clipped at the edge of the plot area. Extend the plot range slightly past the base of the bars to leave room for the border line.

The "Control Chart" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app uses a similar technique to prevent plot symbols on a scatter plot from being clipped at the edges of the plot area.

Comment: I set baseValue to 0.1.Now borders are visible and zero values are shown by a thin line. Dont know if thats the correct approach but it works in my case.Thanks :)